# Global Javascript vars in jQuery selector callback function

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am trying to call Ajax with jQuery and need to pass a variable that is set with PHP on the page load, to two separate functions to either move my calendar forward or backwards by the months.

```
var ajax_load = "Loading...",
    loadUrl = "calendar_backend.php",
    month = parseInt(<?php echo $month ?>);
    console.log(month);
    month = <?php echo $month ?>;

$("#calendar_box").on("click",'#next_month',function(){  
    console.log(month);
    $("#calendar")  
        .html(ajax_load)  
            .load(loadUrl, "month=" + month + "&go=next");
    var month = ++month;

    console.log(month);
});

$("#calendar_box").on("click",'#previous_month',function(){  
    $("#calendar")  
        .html(ajax_load)  
            .load(loadUrl, "month" + month + "&go=previous");  
    var month = --month;
});
```

I have the console calls in there to try to debug this and I get 4 from the first .log() undefined from the second one, and NaN from the third. From those three I can see that the variable is not getting passed into the .on() handler function.

The calender generating page is included_once on the index page and then the AJAX would be used to regenerate the correct data for the month. I need the month passed in the get string to know how far from the current month i need to offset.

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: You need to get rid of the `var` keyword in the functions. Also, when you use the increment/decrement operators, you should not also use an assignment; just `++month` or `--month` by itself is all you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply don't use the `var` keyword inside the function body. `var` will instanciate a new variable inside the `success function`. And you using the decress/incresse operator wrong, its only `month++;` and `month--;`

```
var ajax_load = "Loading...",
    loadUrl = "calendar_backend.php",
    month = parseInt(<?php echo $month ?>);
    console.log(month);
    month = <?php echo $month ?>;

$("#calendar_box").on("click",'#next_month',function(){  
    console.log(month);
    $("#calendar")  
        .html(ajax_load)  
            .load(loadUrl, "month=" + month + "&go=next");
    month++; // Removed var and incressing

    console.log(month); 
});

$("#calendar_box").on("click",'#previous_month',function(){  
    $("#calendar")  
        .html(ajax_load)  
            .load(loadUrl, "month" + month + "&go=previous");  
    month--; // Removed var and decressing
});
```

Comment: I updated with your suggestions and suggestion from the jQuery site [How jQuery Works](http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works#Callback_with_arguments) and set up functions to call in the jQuery.on("click"), `function next_month(month){
     console.log(month);
     $("#calendar").html(ajax_load).load(loadUrl, "month=" + month + "&go=next");month++;console.log(month);}`
 `$("#calendar_box").on("click",'#next_month',function(){next_month(month);});)`  But when I click again its still using the original value for month, and is not updating.

Comment: Got is sorted! Thanks a bunch!!